# Magento 2 Route.xml File not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, controllers

I created a simple module Wow_Page to create a Hello world page using route.xml with the help of magento 2 devdocs. But when i type the route in the url it is showing 404 error page not found.
My Code is as bellow- 
app/code/Wow/Page/registration.php

```
 <?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Wow_Page',
    __DIR__
);
```

app/code/Wow/Page/etc/module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_FirstUnit" setup_version="0.0.1"> <sequence>
        <module name="Wow_Page"/> </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/Wow/Page/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="learning" frontName="test">
            <module name="Wow_Page" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and finally the controller file
app/code/Wow/Page/Controller/Page/View.php

```
 <?php /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Wow\Page\Controller\Page;
class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
    {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * View  page action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data = ['message' => 'Hello world!'];

        return $result->setData($data);
    } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module.xml is incorrect

app/code/Wow/Page/etc/module.xml

Your current module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_FirstUnit" setup_version="0.0.1"> <sequence>
        <module name="Wow_Page"/> </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

replace with below code

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Wow_Page" setup_version="0.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

you have added self-module into `<sequence></sequence>`, you can't do it into self-module, try it in another module if you need it otherwise leave it.

run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: you are welcome :)